# how to rotate lists in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am really new in prolog programing and I can just ask simple questions.

I want to rotate lists to left in prolog like following:

```
rotatelist([1,2,3,4],R)   
R=[2,3,4,1]
```

I tried the following code:

```
rotatelist([],[]).   
rotatelist([H1|T1],[H2|T2]) :- rotatelist(H1,T2).
```

Comment: I finally got around to [writing a general one](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/code/rotate_list.pl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
rotatelist(List, R):- rotatelist(List, R1, H), R = [H|R1].
rotatelist([H], [], H).
rotatelist([H|T], L, R) :- rotatelist(T, T1, R), L = [H|T1].
```

Comment: `rotatelist(L,[1,2]),false.` does not terminate. See magus' solution.

Answer (score 9):

Why use recursion.. isn't this just a case of moving the head to the end of the tail ?

```
rotatelist([H|T], R) :- append(T, [H], R).
```

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer, and BTW it can be used to rotate right or left depending on the argument order.

Answer (score -1):

```
rotatelist([H|T],R) :- append(T,[H],R1),rotatelist_2(R1,R).
rotatelist_2(R,R).
rotatelist_2(R1,R) :- rotatelist(R1,R).
```

Comment: `rotatelist([1,2],L),false.` does not terminate.